# Remove EventListener by returning false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My `_()` function takes a HTML element ID and returns `document.getElementById(str)`. Below I have many eventListeners that either listen for a button click or keyboard event. However since this JS file is shared among many pages, some HTML Elements do not exist for certain pages, thus the `addEventListener()` function spits out an error and terminates the execution everytime it tries to bind a event listener to a non-existent HTML Element. **How can I prevent this from happening and let the code execution continue? In other words, how can I catch these errors?**

```
function _(str) {
    var k = document.getElementById(str);
    if(k){
        return document.getElementById(str);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}



document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    //Button Event Listeners

    _("commentlink").addEventListener("click", showCommentBox);

    _("help_retract").addEventListener("click", function () {
        $(".help_box").toggle(500);
        _("commentlink").style.display = "block";
        $("#commentbox").hide();

    })

    _("help_link").addEventListener("click", function () {
        $("#help_box").toggle(500);
    });

    _("q-help-link").addEventListener("click", function (){
        $("#q-help").toggle(500);

    });

    _("comment-textbox").addEventListener("keyup", checkCharLength);

    _("submit-comment").addEventListener("click", submitComment);

    _("voteUp").addEventListener("click", function () {
        submitVote(1);
    })

    _("voteDown").addEventListener("click", function () {
        submitVote(-1);
    })

    //Automatic Events:
    if (checkCookie("comm_sub")) {
        showCommentBox();
    }
});
```

Comment: Your `_` function is essentially a wrapper for `document.getElementById`, except it returns `false` instead of `null` when an element is not found. Think about why you even need the `_` function.

Comment: @Halcyon I use the `_()` function because it shortens up the code. Instead of having to type `document.getElementById()` every time.

Comment: Last Resort: Url checking perhaps ?

Comment: If by that you mean that it's a good idea to know which elements occur on which page. Hell yea that's a good idea. Or just use jQuery, it swallows errors like nobody's business.

Comment: @DavidYue You are using jQuery already, why not also use its built-in selector and the `.on()` method? It would shorten up the code more than using a new selector function with `.addEventListener()`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this function:

```
window.onerror = function(){
    return true;
}
```

If that doesn't work, surround each `.addEventListener` with:

```
try {
    // .addEventListener here
} catch (e) { // Ignore Errors }
```